# How to define custom permissions for organic groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I would like to define some organic group permissions for a custom entity. The permissions should look like:

```
  $perms += array(
        "create $type content" => array(
          'title' => t('Create %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
        ),
        "update own $type content" => array(
          'title' => t('Edit own %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
        ),
        "update any $type content" => array(
          'title' => t('Edit any %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
        ),
        "delete own $type content" => array(
          'title' => t('Delete own %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
        ),
        "delete any $type content" => array(
          'title' => t('Delete any %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
        ),
      );
```

How do I do this? I found the function  [og_get_permissions()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_get_permissions/7) to get all set permission, but how to modify this array?

Or may be it should be another way round? You set a normal drupal permission first with:

```
function custom_example_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

And then make it eligible on the permission preferences page of OG? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here:](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/og/tree/og.api.php?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-2.x#l14)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_og_permission().
 */
function custom_permissions_og_permission() {
  $name = "taks";
  return array(
    'update own task content' => array(
      'title' => t('Update own %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
      'description' => t("Edit own %type_name content.", array('%type_name' => $name)),
      // Determine to which role to limit the permission. For example the
      // "subscribe" can't be assigned only to a non-member, as a member doesn't
      // need it.
      'roles' => array(OG_AUTHENTICATED_ROLE, OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
      // Determine to which roles the permissions will be enabled by default.
      'default role' => array(OG_AUTHENTICATED_ROLE, OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
    ),
    'update any task content' => array(
      'title' => t('Update any %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
      'description' => t("Edit any %type_name content.", array('%type_name' => $name)),
      'roles' => array(OG_AUTHENTICATED_ROLE, OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
      'default role' => array(OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
    ),
    'create new task content' => array(
      'title' => t('Create new %type_name content', array('%type_name' => $name)),
      'description' => t("Create new %type_name content.", array('%type_name' => $name)),
      'roles' => array(OG_AUTHENTICATED_ROLE, OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
      'default role' => array(OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
    ),
  );
}
```